# One Rest API that call another Rest API

Tags: java, rest, web-services, design-patterns, backend

For example, there are API A and API B. API A have a method GET `http://localhost:8080/apiA/user` to get all the user information from the database. I need to design an API C. When calling the GET `http://localhost:8080/apiC/user`, API C will take the request and send the request to API A and then get the response from API A and send the response(for example like JSON data) as a POST request to API B. Any idea about that?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Where exactly is the problem? What did you try so far, and where did it fail? You might want to read [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to create a minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Well, and what's your problem with it?

I'd suggest you using Spring and its `RestTemplate` for this purpose like this (assuming is your C endpoint):

```
User user = restTemplate.getForEntity(
  "/apiA/user",
  User.class
).getBody();

int requestCounter;
HttpStatus responseStatus;
while(responseStatus != OK || ++requestConter == 3) {
  ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(
    "/apiB/user",
    HttpMethod.POST,
    user,
    String.class
  );
  responseStatus = response.getStatusCode();
}
```

So I hope it can help.

Comment: For the API B, it just gets the Post requests, adds them in the database for future use and returns 200. Need to use API C to maintain the requests and keep sending them to the API B.  Any method for Jersey?

Comment: @HenlenLee keep sending while not getting 200 success or what?

Comment: Store these requests and keep sending 2 or 3 times while not getting 200. If still not getting 200, just remove it and send the next request.

Comment: @HenlenLee well, it's kinda very strange requirements, but you can try something like I wrote.

Comment: Thank you for your helping.

Comment: @HenlenLee that's fine) mark my answer as correct if it something that you need)